# Terraform Multiple Providers S3 AccessDenied: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Hello I am trying to deploy s3 buckets in multiple regions

```
provider "aws" {
  region      = var.region
  max_retries = "100"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.aws_role
  }
  alias = "x"
}

provider "aws" {
  region      = var.backup_region
  max_retries = "100"
  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.role_to_assume_arn
  }
  alias = "y"
}

module "a" {
  providers = {
    aws.x = aws.x
  }
}

module "b" {
  providers = {
    aws.y = aws.y
  }
}
```

#### Inside the module providers.tf for module a

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      configuration_aliases = [
        aws.x
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting a Access Denied for S3 which is weird because the role has permissions to create s3.

Am I passing in providers correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work *if* you are referencing the provider in each resource within the module by alias, like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  provider = aws.x
}
```

But, if you just use the default provider then you probably want to pass in your regional aliased provider as the default provider.

So in module a:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

And when you when you instantiate the module:

```
module "a" {
  providers = {
    aws = aws.x
  }
}
```

Then you can just create your resources in the module normally.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
}
```

Comment: That worked... im not sure why what I had before didnt work.. interesting and confusing thank you though